# Python scope / namespace issue

Tags: python, namespaces, scope

I have two python modules:

//// funcs.py

```
from classes import *

def func():
    d = D()
    print "func"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    c = C()
```

//// classes.py

```
from funcs import *

class C:
    def __init__(self):
        print "C class"
        func()

class D:
    def __init__(self):
        print "D class"
```

---

Running funcs.py yields a NameError saying that "global name 'D' is not defined". However if I comment out the creation of the D() instance, everything works fine.

Why does this happen?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

This one works fine without complicating your code:

///funcs.py

```
import classes

def func():
    d = classes.D()
    print "func"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    c = classes.C()
```

///classes.py

```
import funcs

class C:
    def __init__(self):
        print "C class"
        funcs.func()

class D:
    def __init__(self):
        print "D class"
```

Sometimes it's much better to use simple import, than `from ... import ...`.
There is quite good article on that:
http://effbot.org/zone/import-confusion.htm

Answer (score 2):

The problem occurs due to the attempt to use a cyclically imported module during module initialization. To clarify, using the "from *module* use *" requires that a module be compiled. Instead if you switch to using "import module" in both cases, it should work fine.

Comment: "requires that a module be compiled" is misleading at best. The module code is loaded, compiled and run either way. But `from m import *` copies everything that's in the module at that point in time while `import m` gives a reference to the module object - and hence makes later modifications visible.